# Getting a query string from Google Play via the broadcast receiver?

Tags: java, android, cordova, google-play

I would like to be able to get a query string from a Google Play install passed to my **Cordova** app. I'm stuck on getting it to reliably work, never mind getting it to run after a Google Play install. I've tried both dynamic and static broadcast receivers and briefly had the static one working.. but now it doesn't.

Edit: first, let me add that I get this output from trying and failing to inject a broadcast (detailed below). (My phone is not rooted... does **`adb shell am broadcast`** work properly without root?):

```
D/AndroidRuntime(19631):
D/AndroidRuntime(19631): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime(19631): CheckJNI is OFF
D/AndroidRuntime(19631): setted country_code = USA
D/AndroidRuntime(19631): setted countryiso_code = US
D/AndroidRuntime(19631): setted sales_code = ATT
D/AndroidRuntime(19631): readGMSProperty: start
D/AndroidRuntime(19631): readGMSProperty: already setted!!
D/AndroidRuntime(19631): readGMSProperty: end
D/AndroidRuntime(19631): addProductProperty: start
D/dalvikvm(19631): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm(19631): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm(19631): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm(19631): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm(19631): No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(19631): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 194 unimplemented (abstract)
methods
D/AndroidRuntime(19631): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
D/AndroidRuntime(19631): Shutting down VM
```

For the static version, here is what is in my XML manifest file:

```
<receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.flyingsoftgames.googleplayquery.QueryReceiver ">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And, I have two files, GooglePlayQuery.java and then QueryReceiver.java.
GooglePlayQuery.java:

```
package com.flyingsoftgames.googleplayquery;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.content.Intent;

public class GooglePlayQuery extends CordovaPlugin {
  public static CallbackContext queryCallback = null;
  public static CordovaInterface cordova = null;

  @Override public void initialize (CordovaInterface initCordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
    cordova = initCordova;
    super.initialize (cordova, webView);
  }

  public boolean execute (String action, JSONArray inputs, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if ("getURI".equals(action)) {this.queryCallback = callbackContext;}
    return true;
  }
}
```

QueryReceiver.java:

```
package com.flyingsoftgames.googleplayquery;

import com.flyingsoftgames.googleplayquery.GooglePlayQuery;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

import android.util.Log;

public class QueryReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d ("QueryReceiver", "com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"); // <-- doesn't log this.
    GooglePlayQuery.queryCallback.sendPluginResult (new PluginResult (PluginResult.Status.OK, intent.toURI()));

    // Now destroy the broadcast receiver since we don't need it anymore.
    Activity activity = GooglePlayQuery.cordova.getActivity ();
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName (activity, QueryReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = activity.getPackageManager ();
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting (receiver, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
  }
}
```

I am running this to test it:

`adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.mygame/com.flyingsoftgames.googleplayquery.QueryReceiver --es "referrer" "textinreferrer"`

I have no response from `onReceive`.

Here is my dynamic broadcast receiver version. I run this to test the dynamic version:

`adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.mygame/com.flyingsoftgames.googleplayquery.GooglePlayQuery --es "referrer" "textinreferrer"`

No response from `onReceive` here, either. Any tips?

```
package com.flyingsoftgames.googleplayquery;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;

import android.util.Log;

public class GooglePlayQuery extends CordovaPlugin {
  public static CallbackContext queryCallback = null;
  private BroadcastReceiver receiver = null;

  @Override public void initialize (CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
    super.initialize (cordova, webView);
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.setPriority (999);
    intentFilter.addAction ("com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER");
    Log.d ("GooglePlayQuery", "initialize"); // <-- runs.
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver () {
      @Override public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d ("GooglePlayQuery", "com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"); // <-- No response.
        queryCallback.sendPluginResult (new PluginResult (PluginResult.Status.OK, intent.toURI()));
      }
    };
    webView.getContext().registerReceiver (this.receiver, intentFilter);
  }

  public boolean execute (String action, JSONArray inputs, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    Log.d ("GooglePlayQuery", "execute"); // <-- runs.
    if ("getURI".equals(action)) this.queryCallback = callbackContext;
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I'm not entirely sure on how exactly to get the dynamic format to actually work, but it seems that the static format needs the receiver to be re-enabled via the package manager -- the broadcast receiver doesn't automatically re-enable the receiver when the app runs. In my case:

```
Activity activity = cordova.getActivity ();
ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName (activity, QueryReceiver.class);
PackageManager pm = activity.getPackageManager ();
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting (receiver, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```